# Woocommerce EU VAT Number plugin - How to add extra conditions for VAT exemption from custom dropdown?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

https://woocommerce.com/products/eu-vat-number/

In the documention it mentions things about excluding or including specific countries.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_eu_vat_number_country_codes', 'woo_custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes' );
function woo_custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes( $vat_countries ) {
    $display_vat = array_diff($vat_countries, ['SE', 'GB']); // remove countries in second array
    return array_values($display_vat); // reindex array
}
```

I would like to do the same but then for values of a custom dropdown field.
Eg. If private customer, then don't show the VAT Number Field and also not remove the VAT.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue by detaching and prepending the field with jQuery.

```
  if (jQuery('#wc_billing_field_7378 :selected').text() === 'Zakelijk') {
        jQuery('.woocommerce-billing-fields__fieldwrapper').prepend(vatfieldprepend);
        } 

  else{
        vatfieldprepend = jQuery('#woocommerce_eu_vat_number_field').detach();
    }   
  }).change();
```